# Transform a pretty-printed table to a single line with separators, using Awk

Tags: bash, awk, text-parsing, separator

Trying to clean up output from a Python client. This is an example:

```
+--------------------------+-----------+
| Text                     | Test      |
+--------------------------+-----------+
| 111-222-333-444-55555555 | 123456789 |
| 111-222-333-444-55555555 | 123456789 |
| 111-222-333-444-55555555 | 123456789 |
+--------------------------+-----------+
```

I started by removing the top and bottom by piping the output with:

```
Command_Output | tail -n +4 | head -n -1 |
```

So now we have the following:

```
| 111-222-333-444-55555555 | 123456789 |
| 111-222-333-444-55555555 | 123456789 |
| 111-222-333-444-55555555 | 123456789 |
```

Now I'm trying to remove the pipes in the table and convert the table to a single comma-separated line. It's important to still keep the correlation between the two numbers, though, so maybe I should use two delimiters. Perhaps the final output should look like the following:

```
111-222-333-444-55555555~123456789,111-222-333-444-55555555~123456789,111-222-333-444-55555555~123456789
```

So now I'm at this point:

```
Command_Output | tail -n +4 | head -n -1 | awk '{$3 = "~"; print $0;}'
```

Can someone help me with the last part? I need to get the table into a single, comma-delimited line.

Comment: The whole job can be done in a single `awk` command; no need for `tail`, `head`, `sed` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Command_Output | tail -n +4 | head -n -1 | awk -vORS=, '{ print $2 "~" $4 }' | sed 's/,$/\n/'
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: You don't need a bunch of other tools and pipes when you're using awk. Also, this is limited to exactly 2 input columns and relies on non-portable sed bahavior (`\n` for a newline) and on GNU awk (no space after `-v`) and undefined POSIX behavior (expecting sed to be able to handle input with no terminating newline).

Answer (score 2):

[Atomiklan's own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38538066/45375) works, but:

- is limited to a *single* group of input lines, all of which are output as a single output line.

  - If *no grouping logic* is needed, consider [Ed Morton's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38543030/45375).
- uses several *GNU*-specific options, which won't generally work on non-Linux platforms.
- uses *4* external processes, when *1* will do.

A generalized solution that outputs each block of lines sharing the same (conceptually) first column value as a single line, using only a single, POSIX-compliant `awk` command (still assumes a *2-column* layout):

```
 ... | awk '
  NR <= 3 || /^\+/ { next }                          # skip header and footer
  prev != "" && prev != $2 { printf "\n"; fsep="" }  # see if new block is starting
  { printf "%s", fsep $2 "~" $4; fsep=","; prev=$2 } # print line at hand
  END { printf "\n" }                                # print final newline
'
```

To handle a *variable number of columns*:

```
... | awk -F ' *\\| *' '
  NR <= 3 || /^\+/ { next }                          # skip header and footer
  {                                                  # process each data row
    fsep=""; first=1
    for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {                          # loop over all fields
      if ($i == "") continue                         # skip empty fields
      # See if a new block is starting and print the appropriate record
      # separator.      
      if (first) {  
        if (prev != "") printf (prev != $i ? "\n" : ",") 
        prev=$i                                      # save record's 1st nonempty field
        first=0                                      # done with 1st nonempty field
      }
      printf "%s", fsep $i                           # print field at hand.
      fsep="~"                                       # set separator for subsequent fields
    }
  }
  END { printf "\n" }                                # print trailing newline
'
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work in all awks for any number of input columns:

```
$ awk -F ' *[|] *' -v OFS='~' 'NF>1 && ++c>1 {$1=$1; gsub(/^~|~$/,""); printf "%s%s", (c>2?",":""), $0} END{print ""}' file
111-222-333-444-55555555~123456789,111-222-333-444-55555555~123456789,111-222-333-444-55555555~123456789
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler awk-based solution:

```
Command | awk -vORS=, '($1=="|" && NR>3 ) {print $2"~"$4}'
```

This, however, leaves a trailing `,` at the end. To fix that:

```
Command | awk -vORS= '($1=="|" && NR>3 ) {if (NR>4) {print ","}; print $2"~"$4}'
```

which gives:

```
111-222-333-444-55555555~123456789,111-222-333-444-55555555~123456789,111-222-333-444-55555555~123456789
```

Comment: Seductively simple, but (a) it is generally ill-advised to distinguish the header row from data rows by their _content_ only (there may be no reliable distinction) and (b) your solution adds a trailing `,` rather than a newline to the output.

Comment: Fixed it above using NR instead.

Comment: Better, but now you're missing a trailing `\n` (which utilities generally expect at the end of a file).

Comment: Not having a space after the `-v` makes this unnecessarily gawk-specific.